# Jest mock not returning expected value

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I've found that a mock I'm using, which will return a string, is seemingly returning `jest.fn()` rather than the "implementation" of the mock being `jest.fn().mockImplementation(...)`.

I'm calling it as so:

```
const mockDefaultQuery = 'query { mock }'
jest.mock('../functions', () => (
{
    getArticle: jest.fn().mockName('getArticle').mockImplementation(() => {
        return {}
    }),
    defaultQuery: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return mockDefaultQuery
    })
})
)
```

but the call to defaultQuery from the imported 'functions' library returns [Function mockConstructor] in the test scope rather than "query { mock }" as defined by the const it should be returning.

I've also tried using `jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockDefaultQuery)` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `jest.mock` will be hoisted at the top of your test file during compilation, [have a look here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html#using-with-es-module-imports). So you can never use something in the module scope inside of the mock definition. So your code is evaluated like this

```
jest.mock('../functions', () => (
{
    getArticle: jest.fn().mockName('getArticle').mockImplementation(() => {
        return {}
    }),
    defaultQuery: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return mockDefaultQuery
    })
})
)
const mockDefaultQuery = 'query { mock }'
```

What I normally do in this cases is to create an empty mock and fill it up afterwards:

```
jest.mock('../functions', () => jest.fn())
import myFunction from '../functions'
const mockDefaultQuery = 'query { mock }'
myFunction.mockImplementation( () => (
{
    getArticle: jest.fn().mockName('getArticle').mockImplementation(() => {
        return {}
    }),
    defaultQuery: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return mockDefaultQuery
    })
}))
```

Comment: Hmm I was still getting a similar behaviour after implementing that pattern. What I did notice resolved the issue was to convert what I was mocking from a const to a function. Not sure if the nature of how I was referring to the const was preventing the mock to call it's implementation (i.e. defaultQuery vs defaultQuery()) but it's an acceptable work around for me for now!